# Saving multiple column values using a for loop in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

In my database (SQLite), I would like to update every column in a given row by using a for loop through a dictionary. I've searched both SO and Django documentation, but have been unable to find any information regarding updating multiple columns via a for loop. I suspect that there's an easy solution to my problem, but I've run out of keywords to google.

Here's a very simple example that boils the problem down to its core:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class author_ratings(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    book_one = models.IntegerField()
    book_two = models.IntegerField()
    book_three = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
from models import author_ratings

ratings_dictionary = {'book_one': 10, 'book_two': 20, 'book_three': 30}

current_author = author_ratings.objects.filter(name="Jim")

for book,rating in ratings_dictionary:
    current_author.book = rating
    current_author.save()
```

The problem: Instead of saving the values of 10, 20, and 30 into the corresponding columns of this author's row, Django throws the following error:

"AttributeError: 'current_author' object has no attribute 'book'"

**EDIT:**
In the answers below, Shafikur Rahman correctly points out that 'book' is not an available field (only "name", "book_one", "book_two", and "book_three" are available). My question becomes: how do you use a for loop to update every field without having to hardcode all of them?

For example, I want to avoid having to explicitly type out every column:

```
current_author.book_one = ratings_dictionary['book_one']
current_author.book_two = ratings_dictionary['book_two']
current_author.book_three = ratings_dictionary['book_three']
current_author.save()
```

The above information should be enough to fully understand the question, but I can provide any other details upon request.
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views.py you can:

```
from models import author_ratings

ratings_dictionary = {'book_one': 10, 'book_two': 20, 'book_three': 30}

current_author = author_ratings.objects.filter(name="Jim")

current_author.update(**ratings_dictionary)
```

You can read about `update` [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update).

Answer (score 2):

With `current_author = author_ratings.objects.filter(name="Jim")` you get back a `QuerySet`, not an instance of model. So by doing

```
   current_author.book_one = ratings_dictionary['book_one']
   current_author.book_two = ratings_dictionary['book_two']
   current_author.book_three = ratings_dictionary['book_three']
   current_author.save()
```

you'll still get errors. `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'` at least.

But querysets have the `update` method, which could save you a few lines of code if you don't insist on using a loop:

`current_author.update(**ratings_dictionary)` is all you need

Answer (score 1):

Your `author_ratings` model doesn't have field `book` so it's through error. The available fields are `name`, `book_one`, `book_two`, and `book_three`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess my question is: how do you use a for loop to avoid having to hard code every field? For example, if I have 100 columns that need to be updated, I'd rather not have to list all 100 fields for each author.

Comment: Ok. Something I need to clear. Can you give an idea about your` ratings_dictionary`?